# getting value from input box through lable in jquery

Tags: codeigniter

i have form..in that form i have preview button when i click on preview button i display a popup window..

when user enter values after click on preview button i want to show those values in my popup window..(before submit)in codeigniter please help me how to do this in codeigniter..thank you

Now I want to see the preview of the given data into popup before submit the form ..

```
    <div class="modal-body">


    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel ">
                            <div class="panel-heading hidden_color">NOTIFICATION</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:;"> <!-- form horizontal acts as a row -->
                                    <!-- normal control -->
                                    <div class="form-group mod_mr20">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mod_mr20">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Expires By</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mod_mr20">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Notice  visible to</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mod_mr20">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Attach Files</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mod_mr20">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Notice Description</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>




                                    <div class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">CLOSE</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>



                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- #end col-left -->
     </div>

    </div>


  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on ('keyup','#kp', function () {
       var value=$(this).val();
      
        $('#kpview').val(value);
    });

$(document).on ('change','#selectbox', function () {
       var selectval=$(this).val();
      
        $('#resultselect').val(selectval);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Key Pressed: <input type="text" id="kp" />&nbsp; 

Char val: <input type="text" id="kpview" /><br/>

<select id="selectbox"><option value="option1">option one</option> <option value="option2">option two</option></select>
                                             
  <select id="resultselect"><option value="option1">option one</option>
    <option value="option2">option two</option></select>
```

Its very simple.Give your form an **ID** and **on click of preview button or on submit**(if preview button is submit) simply **serialize** the form data and store it in variable.You can specifically append each input data to the specific sections of your modal or Simply iterate it in an $.each

```
<form id="form"></form>

<script>
//$('#form').submit() or
$( "#previewbtn" ).click(function() {
var arr=[]; //array
arr= $('form').serialize(); // serialize that form

$('modalfields').html(arr.specificfield);

or

$.each( arr, function(key,value ) {
    $('modalfields').html(value);
});

});


</script>
```

note: correct me if I had done some syntax errors as I'm not a Pro :D .

Comment: Yes using jquery only. You can submit the form after user clicks ok/confirm btn (inside or outside modal) using $('form').submit(); or simply submit the form as usual

Comment: actually i want to get value from input box when user types name it should display in preview popup as well

Comment: like by using onkeyup function

Comment: yeah sure we can... try   $(document).on("keydown","some_selector",function() { $('preview_section').html(that_content);  });

Comment: can you please explain..where i used this code in my view page

Comment: simply use the code in end of page inside a <script> </script>... can you clearly say it.. whether you need to display after clicking preview button or when typing at sametime each letter display in preview window?

Comment: ya exactly ..when typing at sametime each letter display in preview window

Comment: see the code snippet I attached now.. hope it helps :)

Comment: how to write for dropdowns

Comment: hi mr.balu anand can you please tell me how to store value for textarea

Comment: can't get you .. store value in db?